# Marshalling an object that has object fields

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

Not sure if the title makes any sense.
I have an object that I want to marshal using JAXB that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "subscriptionRequest")
    public class RegistrationRequest {

    private Long id;
    private RegistrationSource registrationSource;
    }
```

The RegistrationSource object:

```
 public class RegistrationSource {

    private Integer id;
    private String code;
}
```

I want to create an xml that has the following layout:

```
<subscriptionRequest registrationSource="0002">
    ...
</subscriptionRequest>
```

where the registrationSource attribute value is the code field value from the RegistrationSource object.

What xml annotations do I need to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@XmlAttribute` on `registrationSource`, `@XmlValue` on `code`. Note that in this case you also should have `@XmlTransient` on other fields of `RegistrationSource`, such as `id`

**EDIT:** This works:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "subscriptionRequest") 
public class RegistrationRequest { 

    private Long id; 
    private RegistrationSource registrationSource; 

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    @XmlAttribute
    public RegistrationSource getRegistrationSource() { return registrationSource; }
    public void setRegistrationSource(RegistrationSource registrationSource)
    {
        this.registrationSource = registrationSource;
    }
}
```

-

```
public class RegistrationSource { 

    private Integer id; 
    private String code; 

    @XmlTransient
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    @XmlValue
    public String getCode() { return code; }
    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
}
```

Comment: I get the following exception:

        Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
        @XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.

Comment: Before you write down this code I put the annotations on the fields declaration. After I saw your code and applied the changes, I get these:
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 5 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.
.
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
.
@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.
.
Class has two properties of the same name "registrationSource"
.
Class has two properties of the same name "code"

Comment: I guess this implementation would work only for marshal right? What if I wanted it to work for unmarshalling too? Shouldn't the annotation's be on the fields' declarations?

Thanks a lot for your time. I will be able to respond to any posts by tomorrow.

Comment: This code works fine for both marshalling and unmarshalling (hovewer, in `RegistrationService` only `code` field is unmarshalled, because if you use `@XmlValue`, you should mark other fields `@XmlTransient`)

Comment: I it useful to look at answer: [JaxB Unmarshalling with XmlMixed Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057726/jaxb-unmarshalling-with-xmlmixed-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate this class automatically using some tools , then try this - 
Generate xsd from your xml using tools like [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html), and then generate java file from xsd using jaxb. Life would be much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

The lame approach would be to add something like

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "registrationSource")
private String getCode() {
    return registrationSource.code;
}
```

to your `RegistrationSource` -- but there must be a more elegant way...

Comment: This one works, but as you say it's a bit lame. I'll wait for responses to the other suggestions and if no other possible solution is given, I will mark this as the accepted one. Thanks

ps: it's like the second solution sb mentioned before you, but it seems he erased his post.

Comment: I have to note that in this occasion I also have to put the @XmlTransient annotation on registrationSource object, so that it doesn't show up as an element too.